# Require.js: When extending a module can I use prototype directly or I should use extend as well?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, module, requirejs, underscore.js

If I am using Require.js for managing modules in a project with Backbone.js (which also has underscore), when extending a module I can do something like this

```
require(['Home'], function(home) {

    'use strict';

    var view = home.View.prototype;

    _.extend(view,{

        anotherTitle: 'Welcome Jean Luc Picard';

    });
});
```

or

```
require(['Home'], function(home) {

    'use strict';

    var view = home.View.prototype;

        view.anotherTitle= 'Welcome Jean Luc Picard'; //this is a new attribute

});
```

what is the most approrpiate way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use extend.

Remember that modifying a prototype of a Backbone type (which is what I assume `home.View` to be) will extend/modify that prototype for all consumers, which might be unexpected behavior.  Even when using require, you can modify those dependencies directly and impact subsequent require calls (this happens because you're modifying the dependency in the require cache, so subsequent requests to the same dependency don't need to occur).

Using `.extend()` is the best way to create your own extended/custom types.  Behind the scenes, `extend()` does in fact modify the prototype, but it's the prototype of the new object type created and effectively uses the backbone type as a super.

So, to create your own type:

```
// Create a new object whose prototype is the combination of Backbone.View 
// and the object passed to extend
var MyCustomView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });
var instance = new MyCustomView();
```

If, however, `home.View` is a custom view type already, it's functionally probably equivalent to either do a `.extend` on it or adding things to the prototype manually.  However, for consistency and clarity's sake, you should always use the handy dandy `extend method` to create a sub type.

```
var MySubCustomView = MyCustomView.extend({ ... });
var instance = new MySubCustomView();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and complete answer!

Comment: You are welcome. If you found it answered your question, please remember to mark it as the answer with a check mark so people can see the question as resolved.